# Android - MediaPlayer exception in Android4.0

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, video-recording

I am using Video Recording in my Android Application. It works fine in `Android2.2` and `Android2.3` devices but the application is crashing in `Android4.0` .

**Here is my code:**

```
  class VideoPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
  {
  MediaRecorder recorder;
  SurfaceHolder holder = null; 
  FileOutputStream fileout; 
 public VideoPreview(Context context,MediaRecorder temprecorder) {
 super(context);
    recorder= temprecorder;
    holder= getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);
    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
   }
  public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    }
  public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
  {
      if(recorder!=null)
      {
    recorder.release();
    Log.d("Video Preview", "Exception1");
    recorder = null;
      }
  }

  //surfaceChanged : This method is called after the surface is created.
  public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h)
  {
  }
  public void  stop(){

      if(recorder!=null)
      {
      recorder.release();
      recorder = null;
      }        
  }
    @Override 
    public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ 

         return false; 

    } 

  public boolean start()  {     
      String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
      String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/myvideo.mp4";
      File fname = new File(path);
      if (!state.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) return false;
      File directory = new File(path).getParentFile(); 
      if(!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs())   return false; 

          if (recorder == null)    
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();         

           int out_format = MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4;
           //THREE_GPP;
          recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);    
          recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC); 
            recorder.setOutputFormat(out_format); 
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
            //recorder.setMaxDuration(20000); 
            //recorder.setVideoSize(352,288);   // 352, 288 m_recorder.setVideoSize(320, 240); 176,144
            recorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);
            recorder.setOutputFile(fname.getPath());                
           /* videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videosurface);
            SurfaceHolder holder = videoview.getHolder();
            mediarecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());*/             
            recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(6000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!Recorder_Prepare())
            return false;
            else
            return true;
      }    

private boolean Recorder_Prepare()
    {

        try {
            if (recorder != null){
            recorder.prepare();
            Log.d("Video Preview", "Exception2");
            recorder.start();     
            Log.d("Video Preview", "Exception3");
            }
        }
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                return false;
            }
            catch (IOException e) { 
                return false;
            }
            return true;            
    }             
  }
```

Here is my `logcat` throws exception at `recorder.start();` as below:

```
      06-11 13:54:54.926: E/MediaRecorder(22582): start failed: -19
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2201
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582):  at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582):  at  com.Myapp.VideoPreview.Recorder_Prepare(VideoPreview.java:106)
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582):  at com.Myapp.VideoPreview.start(VideoPreview.java:94)
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582):  at com.Myapp.videoRecord$1.run(videoRecord.java:94)
      06-11 13:54:54.961: E/AndroidRuntime(22582):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I verfied the application in [Samsung Nexus S](http://www.google.com/search?q=Samsung%20Nexus%20S&hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3aen-US%3a%7Breferrer%3asource?%7D&prmd=imvnsr&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=crvVT6OnOceqrAek7dH8Dw&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&ved=0CFsQ_AUoAQ&biw=1024&bih=653) and it does not have `SDCard` Support. I googled to solve the problem for 4 hours but cant found the solution. **Are there any deprecated methods in the above program?** Please help me to resolve the problem.

Comment: Is there another exception further down the stacktrace? Look for "Caused by", just below the exception stacktrace you posted.

Comment: @GrahamBorland No CAUSED BY exception in Logcat. What i have posted is onlu the errors i got...

Comment: Have you added  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" /> to your manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 4.0 introduces new runtime checks to make sure you aren't doing something silly like accessing the network on the main thread.

Are you doing something silly like accessing the network on the main thread? Is your media being streamed over the network, and where are you calling your `VideoPreview.start()` method from?

Comment: The video which is recorded is attached to the email and sents the mail to the email recipients. I am not using video which is streamed over the n/w. I am calling VideoPreview.start() after Phone number Calling functionality.